# PHP Printing JSON value

Tags: php, json

I have a JSON array that I want to be able to drill down to a lower level and print just that value. The problem occurs when I reach a level that has is indacted as [0] (or [n]). For example I have the following output, and I want to just print the `game key` for the first league.

This is how I am trying to print it

```
HtmlSpecialChars(print_r($user->fantasy_content->users[0]->user[1]->games[0]->game[0]->game_key,1))
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
```

When I do it incrementally it seems to fail on this command (so I assume I'm not index correctly):

```
$user->fantasy_content->users[0]
```

Here is the output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [fantasy_content] => stdClass Object
        (
            [xml:lang] => en-US
            [yahoo:uri] => /fantasy/v2/users;use_login=1/games
            [users] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [user] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [guid] => IYEZUHTVBYRLIB3OAQC5WRZPQY
                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [games] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [game] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                                        (
                                                                            [game_key] => 147
                                                                            [game_id] => 147
                                                                            [name] => Baseball
                                                                            [code] => mlb
                                                                            [type] => full
                                                                            [url] => http://baseball.fantasysports.yahoo.com/b1
                                                                            [season] => 2006
                                                                        )

                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                    [count] => 1
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [count] => 1
                )

            [time] => 52.390813827515ms
            [copyright] => Data provided by Yahoo! and STATS, LLC
            [refresh_rate] => 60
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For objects you must use the `->` syntax and if the key/property name is a number or has other special characters, you will need to use the `$object->{'0'}` syntax.

The `game_key` can be retrieved using:

```
$user->fantasy_content->users->{'0'}->user[1]->games->{'0'}->game[0]->game_key;
```

Comment: You don't have to use quotation marks, just `$object->{0}` works in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a `stdClass` object to an array by casting it like so:

```
<?php

$array = (array) $myObject;

echo json_encode($array);
```

You can also cast inline:

```
<?php

echo json_encode((array) $object);
```